# Change vertical space constant between iPhone sizes in Xcode or in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, constraints

I have a text two text fields and a button, it looks great on the iPhone 4 and 5 but not on the 6 and 6 Plus, it stretches to much because the keeps the constant stays the same of course.

Is there a way to increase it on the 6 or 6 Plus and keep it the same on the 4 and 5. Im using a vertical stack view and the bottom constraint is linked to the top of the button underneath it.

This is okay
[image: iPhone 4 View]

This size I want to maintain
[image: iPhone 5 View]

Still stretches
[image: iPhone 6 View]

WHY!?
[image: iPhone 6 Plus View]

Comment: have you tried changing the bottom constraint? That should do the trick very easily

Comment: I have then the iPhone 5 and 4 will become very small and ugly. I'm trying to keep what I have on the 4 and 5 and the 6 and and 6 Plus, increase that constant. ( The button is linked on to the top of the keyboard So i constrained to the top of the Sign In Button)

Comment: give the height constraint >=(your desired height)

Comment: Maybe if you create two stacks, one for textField and Forgot Password label and one for the button, so you can create a vertical space constraint between these two constraints. And on the vertical constraint you can put the relation as greater than or equal. Maybe that will solve and you doesn't need to add code.

Answer (score 0):

Just try giving fixed height to vertical stackview, if you want it's subview's to have same height if screenSize grows.